# Regular expression for "parts joined by a delimiter"?

Tags: regex

E.g. I want to test that a string is a comma-separated list, with no empty elements. (That also means the string doesn't begin or end with a comma.)

Procedurally, I could/would do something like this (e.g. JavaScript):

```
function isValid(str) {
    return str.split(',').every(function (substr) {
        return substr.length > 0;
    });
}
```

Can I achieve that with a regex? I'm struggling with doing so, and maybe it's because I'm not experienced with features like lookahead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have it actually.

```
/^[^,]+(,[^,]+)*$/
```

That's saying: start with one or more non-commas, and then if there's anything else, it must be a comma followed by one or more non-commas, repeated.

That *seems* to work in all the cases I've tested:

```
// should pass:
x
xy
x,y
x,y,z

// should fail:
,
x,
,x
,x,
x,y,
,x,y
,x,y,
```

But I'm not sure if I'm missing any cases.

Comment: Too quick for me, I was answering the exact same regex :) It should match all the case : http://www.regexr.com/39lg4

Comment: If you don't allow `,` as part of a token, then this is a good solution. Actual CSV would have to allow them, and the regex will get messy.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the easiest thing to test for is actually what you don't want- a simple expression like:

```
/,\s*,/
```

will match two commas with no non-whitespace characters between them.

Even simpler, a check for `/,,/` will return two neighbouring commas, which will actually be the same as the test you are performing there with the exception that it won't catch an end of line.

This will also catch line start and endings:

```
/^,|,\s*,|,$/  // cuts out whitespace
/^,|,,|,$/     // if you're only interested in neighbouring commas.
```

Comment: What do you think `[\W^,]` matches?

Comment: Good point, I had that left in from when I was testing for the positive and it was getting greedy across commas :)

Comment: Now your regex matches `,,,,` or `,;:!  -(",`.

Comment: Interesting, apparently I'm more familiar with the C# dialect where `\W` does not match punctuation characters. _I've_ learned something today at any rate, thank you.

Comment: `\W` is the negation of `\w`, so it means everything that is not alphabet (depending on locale), digit and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Why regex? Do you want *[another problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)*?

Just keep it simple :

```
function isValid(str)
{

    // if first or last character is comma, its invalid
    if (str.charAt(0)==',' || str.charAt(str.length-1)==',')
        return false;

    // the length of the string    
    var length_before = str.length;

    // the length of the string after checking for empty csv elements (,,)
    var length_after = str.replace(/,,/g,'').length;

    // if there is a difference, there must be an empty element, so its invalid.
    // if there is no difference, is valid.
    return length_before==length_after;

}
```

working examples here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jw6sdu6q/1/

p.s. ironically **i am using** a global identifier for replace, which is the only solution AFAIK, thank you javascript replace function.

Comment: There are uses for regexes. E.g. native HTML5 form validation.